# The "AllIndexOf" method does not work in Forms

Tags: c#, string, list, extension-methods

I've tried all the ways to fix this but none works for me. I test this on class  and it works, but when I added it to a Form it doesn't not work.

```cs
public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    IList<int> allIndexOf = new List<int>();
    int index = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        allIndexOf.Add(index);
        index = text.IndexOf(str, index + str.Length, comparisonType);
    }
    return allIndexOf;
}


public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string number11 = textBox1.Text;
    // count stars
    int stars_count = number11.Split('*').Length - 1;



    var allIndexOf = number11.AllIndexOf("*", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(number11);
    string number11 _all_stars_position = string.Join(",", allIndexOf);
    string[] number11 _array = number11 _all_stars_position.Split(',');
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```cs
var allIndexOf = number11 .AllIndexOf("*", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: That is either missing a "this" in the method declaration if you want it to be an extension method or you  need to call it as `AllIndexOf(number11, /*rest of your parms*/);`

Comment: What the issue you are facing?

Comment: You need to call it like this: `var allIndexOf = AllIndexOf(number11, "*", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` Or create the function as an extension.

Comment: Replace `public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)` with `public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)`

Answer (score 1):

You can to define the method in static class and then use as extension method. make your you pass `this` to the calling parameter.

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        IList<int> allIndexOf = new List<int>();
        int index = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            allIndexOf.Add(index);
            index = text.IndexOf(str, index + str.Length, comparisonType);
        }
        return allIndexOf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AllIndexOf' and no accessible extension method 'AllIndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) splitNumber

Comment: read the error code @hashembaddad and act accordingly, either include a using statement pointing to the namespace where you declared the static class with the extension method, or include the dll (don't forge to include the `this` keyword as vivek showed)

Comment: have you defined class in different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the goal here is to create an extension method for the `string` type. That requires creating a *static* method in a *static* class within the project's *namespace*. Doing so will *extend* any object of `string` type in the namespace and you don't need to move/copy the static class nor the static method to elsewhere.

Suppose you have a WinForms application named `WindowFormsApp1`, a Form named `Form1`, and the Form contains a Button named `button1` calls in it's Click event the extension method in question:

```cs
using System;
sing System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //...
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var text = "Som*e t*ex*t to* se*arch";
            var str = "*";
            var indices = text.AllIndexOf(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", indices));
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str,
            StringComparison comparison) =>
            text.Select((c, i) => i)
            .Where(i => text.Substring(i, str.Length).Equals(str, comparison))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Note the `AllIndexOf` method, you can use the extension methods to create a one liner query as such.

The `button1` prints the following indices for the given text:

```
3, 7, 10, 15, 19, 24
```